# json_remove is removing the wrong value from array on second run

Tags: sql, json, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to remove a value from a json array, however I am having issues.

First I insert the array into into the table like so:

```sql
INSERT into demo (hint) VALUES ('["Hello","World"]');
```

Next when I run this query, the `World` value gets removed which is what is supposed to happen. However if I run it a second time, then the `Hello` value gets removed which is not supposed to happen. What am I doing wrong, or what is a better way to remove items from a json array?

```sql
UPDATE demo SET hint = json_remove(
    hint,
    (SELECT json_each.fullkey FROM demo, json_each(demo.hint) WHERE json_each.value = 'World')
);

select * from demo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery that you use as the path argument of `json_remove()` returns `null` the 2nd time that you execute the update statement because there is no `"World"` in the json array.
In this case `json_remove()` also returns `null`.

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the [`UPDATE...FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax:

```
UPDATE demo AS d
SET hint = json_remove(d.hint, j.fullkey)
FROM json_each(d.hint) AS j
WHERE j.value = 'Hello';
```